# Upload multiple files angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upload mutliple files using angular. An example is on upload i choose 4 files. Here's what I did so far. I tried looping it but its not working.

```
onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.filesToUpload = event.target.files;
    }
  }

saveFileForm() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    const files = this.filesToUpload;

    for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("files", files[i]);

      this.coursemoduleService.uploadFile(
      this.contentDetails.content.id,
      formData).subscribe(
        result => {
          this.formMessageClass = "alert-success";
          this.formMessage = "Content added!";
          formAlert();
          console.log(result);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.formMessageClass = "alert-danger";
          this.formMessage = "Pls. fill required fields correctly!"
          formAlert();
          validateAllFormFields(this.fileForm);
        }
      );

    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: what will be issue you facing while upload

Comment: @harkeshkumar I edited the post and added the error.

Comment: That's an error from whatever server you are hitting. Needs to be debugged in your backend.

Comment: This is server side error, check if you are getting error at server side. If yes post it in question.

Comment: @yulgurz i under what is the problem you have

Comment: @yulgurz we can start conversation

Comment: @harkeshkumar. I already solved the problem. new DataForm must be inside loop.